# Output the loss/cost function in keras

Tags: python, keras, loss-function, regularized

I am trying to find the cost function in Keras. I am running an LSTM with the loss function `categorical_crossentropy` and I added a Regularizer. How do I output what the cost function looks like after my Regularizer this for my own analysis?

```py
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(
    NUM_HIDDEN_UNITS,
    return_sequences=True,
    input_shape=(PHRASE_LEN, SYMBOL_DIM),
    kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.01)
    ))
model.add(Dropout(0.3))
model.add(LSTM(NUM_HIDDEN_UNITS, return_sequences=False))
model.add(Dropout(0.3))
model.add(Dense(SYMBOL_DIM))
model.add(Activation('softmax'))
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
    optimizer=RMSprop(lr=1e-03, rho=0.9, epsilon=1e-08))
```

Comment: What do you mean "looks like"? Are you trying to view the loss when you call the model.fit method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How do i output what the cost function looks like after my regularizer this for my own analysis?

Surely you can achieve this by obtaining the output (`yourlayer.output`) of the layer you want to see and print it (see [here](https://keras.io/layers/about-keras-layers/)). However there are better ways to visualize these things.

Meet [Tensorboard](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/summaries_and_tensorboard).

This is a powerful visualization tool that enables you to track and visualize your metrics, outputs, architecture, kernel_initializations, etc. The good news is that there is already a [Tensorboard Keras Callback](https://keras.io/callbacks/#TensorBoard) that you can use for this purpose; you just have to import it. To use it just pass an instance of the Callback to your `fit` method, something like this:

```
from keras.callbacks import TensorBoard
#indicate folder to save, plus other options
tensorboard = TensorBoard(log_dir='./logs/run1', histogram_freq=1,
    write_graph=True, write_images=False)  

#save it in your callback list
callbacks_list = [tensorboard]
#then pass to fit as callback, remember to use validation_data also
model.fit(X, Y, callbacks=callbacks_list, epochs=64, 
    validation_data=(X_test, Y_test), shuffle=True)
```

After that, start your Tensorboard sever (it runs locally on your pc) by executing:

```
tensorboard --logdir=logs/run1
```

---

For example, this is what my Kernels look like on two different models I tested (to compare them you have to save separate runs and then start Tensorboard on the parent directory instead). This is on the Histograms tab, on my second layer:

[image]

The model on the **left** I initialized with **`kernel_initializer='random_uniform'`**, thus its shape is the one of a Uniform Distribution. The model on the **right** I initialized with **`kernel_initializer='normal'`**, thus why it appears as a Gaussian distribution throughout my epochs (about 30).

This way you could visualize how your kernels and layers "look like", in a more interactive and understandable way than printing outputs. This is just one of the great features Tensorboard has, and it can help you develop your Deep Learning models faster and better.

Of course there are more options to the Tensorboard Callback and for Tensorboard in general, so I do suggest you thoroughly read the links provided if you decide to attempt this. For more information you can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48408236/3908170) and [also this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42112260/how-do-i-use-the-tensorboard-callback-of-keras) questions.

**Edit:** So, you comment you want to know how your regularized loss "looks" analytically. Let's remember that by adding a Regularizer to a loss function we are basically extending the loss function to include some "penalty" or preference in it. So, if you are using `cross_entropy` as your loss function and adding an `l2` regularizer (that is Euclidean Norm) with a weight of 0.01 your whole loss function would look something like:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I am already running tensorboard. I meant specifically how do I output what the full loss function is as a readable function of its inputs. Normally cross_entropy is my loss function, but after adding regularization, I am getting weird loss values. 

For instance, if I was running cross entropy alone, my loss would look like this:

`def loss(yHat, y):`  
    `if yHat == 1:`  
     `return -log(y)`  
     `else:`  
      `return -log(1 - y)`  

But since I added regularization I don't know what it looks like

Comment: @MikeManh ok, so when you apply Regularization to your models, you are basically "extending" your loss function. Say your loss function is `cross_entropy`, your regularized loss function would be `J(x) = cross_entropy(x) + REG`. In this case, as you were using `l2` as regularizer with 0.01 weight it would be `J(x) = cross_entropy(x) + 0.01*l2(x)`. That is the analytical form your Loss Function now has. Did I get you right?